# About webserver ipv6 example

Tags: contiki, coap

I am a beginner in IoT and I will work on Security in CoAP. I needed a basic example and I decided to go on webserver example.

I am using cc2531 and cc2650 and 6lbr now. So I will work on a real testbed and I have some questions regarding the example https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/webserver-ipv6/README.md ;

1. At first step there is written that UIP_CONF_TCP settings of platform, is the platform "srf06-cc26xx" ? Or am I wrong?
2. I receive the error below

   ```
   user@instant-contiki:/etc/6lbr/platform/srf06-cc26xx/sensortag$ ifconfig tap0 inet6 3ffe:0501:ffff:0100:0206:98ff:fe00:0231
   ```

   Do not know how to set addresses for family 10.
   Do you have any suggestion to solve it?
3. and it suggests this settings on radvd but I could not find any such file under "srf06-cc26xx" so should I use another platform for that? AdvPreferredLifetime 400;
   AdvValidLifetime 600;

Since I will use real test bed I am confused between platforms like cooja and sky. I found the radvd conf file under that platforms but not sure about if that platforms needed.

4. I want to implement get put methods between client and server, so is there any detailed source for that implementation which you can recommend ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, srf06-cc26xx would be the platform for your cc2650; it is for TI CC26xx and that supports two boards as mentioned in 
   https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/platform/srf06-cc26xx
2. I do not see any errors?!
3. You can install radvd (it is a tool) by typing: sudo apt-get install radvd
4. cooja is a simulated platform (does not exist in real life) only for trying features on the cooja simulator. Sky is a board like skymote families.

You can use an ipv6 client or even a normal browser for that. There is a webbrowser example. There is contiki's wiki but I doubt that you'll find extensive tutorials on this particular point though.